# tell git pull to ignore a file named con.dat since it can't be checked out on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I'm on Win10 trying to git pull from a repository where a file named con.dat exists - it has been created and then checked into git on different OS obviously. I know why you can't have a file named con.dat on Windows, and I actually don't need that file. I just want the rest of the repository to pull and checkout the other files and not stop and fail when it can't create the con.dat.

The exact error is:

```
error: unable to stat just-written file Resources/CON.dat: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have access to the other OS?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes. Your suggestion is to add it to .gitignore for everyone?

Comment: @Phillip. That depends on the purpose and origin of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sparse checkout.

```
printf >.git/info/sparse-checkout %s\\n \
        '*' '!'{con,prn,aux,nul,lpt[1-9],com[1-9]}{,'.*'} 
git config core.sparsecheckout true
```

You might need to match the committed case, is it con or CON?

Comment: The file is named CON.dat capital filename, lowercase extension

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But that means everyone on the team using Windows would have to do that. So probably deleting the file on a Mac and committing the delete from there is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of sparse checkout and the core.protectNTFS config option to allow Windows reserved filenames that are valid for NTFS (e.g. PRN).

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreprotectNTFS

./git/config:

```
[core]
protectNTFS = false
```